# JS - weird scroll handling behavior on mobile devices

Tags: javascript

I have a functionality on the site I am developing, which resizes a block when you scroll. I do it with two functions:

```
headerHeight: function () {
  this.header = window.innerHeight + 50
  this.minHeader = this.header - 300;
  this.maxHeader = this.header + 300;     
},

handleScroll: function () {
  var hotOffsetTop = this.getElementOffset(document.querySelectorAll('.hot')[0]).top;
  var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (this.lastScrollPos != 0 && scrollPos !=0 && scrollPos < hotOffsetTop) {
    let h = hotOffsetTop - scrollPos   
    let difInPercent = Math.floor((h / 1200) * 100)
    let a =  (difInPercent * (this.maxHeader - this.minHeader)) / 100
    this.header = this.minHeader + a;   
  }         
  this.lastScrollPos = scrollPos;
},
```

When the page is opened these functions are called like that:

```
this.headerHeight();
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
```

getElementOffset is just a function which returns an object with top and left offsets of an element.

The idea is: this header covers all your screen and whe you scroll down it resizes, so it looks like parallax-ish thing and the second block appears faster than you scroll. And when you scroll back, this header covers full screen height again

You can see this in action here: https://zapomni-7b57b.firebaseapp.com/

My problem is that this works well on desktop and in mobile view in chrome, but it doesn't work well on android chrome. Sometimes this block doesn't resize and in most cases when you scroll to top it doesn't cover all screen(it does on desktop). Probably this problem is present on iOS too.

Comment: You are losing scope when adding the handler, just saying.

Comment: @Jonas W. doesn't look like scope issue for me